# Vue.js/Vuex: How do I v-bind to a state value?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to bind the text in a b-dropdown element to a value in the store. I tried binding to a computed property since the value in the store can change and the b-dropdown's text should change dynamically to reflect this change. I want to store the value in the store rather than as a data object because the value has to persist outside of the component where the b-dropdown exists.

Here's the b-dropdown element:

```
<b-dropdown v-bind:text="selectedSearchType" variant="outline-secondary">
  ...
</b-dropdown>
```

And the computed property

```
computed: {
  selectedSearchType: function() {
    return store.getters.getSelectedSearchType
  }
},
```

The getter

```
getSelectedSearchType: state => {
  return state.selectedSearchType
}
```

The state

```
state: {
 selectedSearchType: "Item",
 .....
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "text". Expected String, got Function.
```

Instead if I do

```
<b-dropdown v-bind:text="selectedSearchType()" variant="outline-secondary">
```

I get

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedSearchType' of undefined"
```

How do I fix this to make the b-dropdown's text bind to the selectedSearchType ins the store?

Comment: Would you mind to share the getSelectedSearchType getter with us?

Comment: @DawidZbiński, I've edited my question to include the getter and the state

Comment: How do you import `store` in component?

Comment: I'm importing the store with `import store from '../store/module'`. The store is contained in the module.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet on binding to the store is to create a computed getter/setter and then use v-model in your input.  That would look something like the following, you will have to adjust a little depending on your values.

This also assumes that `b-dropdown` is going to emit an input when the value changes.

```
<b-dropdown v-model="selectedSearchType" variant="outline-secondary">

computed: {
  selectedSearchType: {
    get() { 
      return //value from store 
    },
    set(val) {
      // set the value in the store
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended, but the text of b-dropdown was not displaying the string stored in selectedSearchType. The dropdown just had an arrow, meaning there was no specified text.

Comment: Hmm, on it check what the value is being passed in the vue tools in chrome.  Probably the get function is not returning a value.  I am confident in this approach  b/c i use it  often when mapping to and from the store like this.